# PHP LDAP Extract DN and put it in a Variable once binded and searching an array with cn

Tags: php, arrays, ldap

please see the code here:
http://pastebin.com/ZLHG6m07

This code is working, it binds to the ldap server, the code asks for the user's "username" and "Password" does a secondary bind, and searches an array.  Using the user's CN, I search and create an array, pulling the DN.  The problem is, I don't know how to extract the full DN, from the array, and put it back into a variable properly, so that I can bind and authenticate to the ldap with that user.  Specifically, I am struggling with this part of the code, it does not properly put the [dn] into the $distinguishedName variable:

```
    $ldapCount = @ldap_count_entries($ldapConnection, $ldapSearch);

if (!$ldapCount) {
            die('account not found');
    } else {
    if (!$ldapEntry = @ldap_get_entries($ldapConnection, $ldapSearch)) {
        die('Could not get ldap entry');
    }

    $distinguishedName = $ldapEntry[0]['dn'][0];
    print_r($ldapEntry);

    if (empty($distinguishedName)) {
        die('Account information not found');
    }

    if(!@ldap_bind($ldapConnection, $distinguishedName, $_POST['password']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dn` entry does not contain an array but directly the DN-Entry. So your code should look like this:

```
$distinguishedName = $ldapEntry[0]['dn'];
```

I have created a little gist to illustrate LDAP-Login at https://gist.github.com/heiglandreas/5689592. Have a special look at line 68

Comment: You sir, are a lifesaver.  THANK-YOU SO MUCH 
 
heiglandreas~!!!!  I'm always so close in my code, but sometimes, yet so far!!!  ha ha ha.